# Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED but set memory growth is true

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, gpu

I am trying to run a training model with the following summary:

```
Total params: 36,922,327
Trainable params: 13,361,175
Non-trainable params: 23,561,152
```

And when getting into the first epoch, I get this error:

```
Epoch 1/10
2020-10-19 16:54:15.754590: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-10-19 16:54:18.527087: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:328] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
2020-10-19 16:54:18.532567: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:328] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED
```

My specs are:

```
tensorflow: 2.3.1
CUDA: 10.1
cuDNN: 7.6.5
GPU: GeForce GTX 1070 with Max-Q Design computeCapability: 6.1 coreClock: 1.2655GHz coreCount: 16 deviceMemorySize: 8.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 238.66GiB/s
```

After some googling, I came across `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)` as a solution which I have implemented in my training script.

I am able to run other models that have fewer params so I am assuming my issue has something to do with the size of the model and how much memory it takes up. But since doing `.set_memory_growth` to true is not working, I am not sure.

Any ideas/thoughts are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
So I tried running another script that I wrote that uses the same model (RetinaNet) that worked successfully before and when I ran it today, the same cuDNN error happens. I can't think of a reason why this would change over time, but figured that was important to add.

**EDIT2:**
After some more investigating, it appears the model runs after I restart my computer. BUT then after I cancelled the running of that model, I tried running it again and I get the same cuDNN error.